# Ошибка в Sublime text Не удалось найти указанный файл

Tags: python, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Недавно я написал простой код на python. Он запускался и выдавал ответ, но спустя некоторое время после выполнения программы, в панели выходит ошибка 'Не удалось найти указанный файл'. Я пробовал перезапускать и переустанавливать sublime не помогло. Пробовал переустанавливать python разные версии, но и это не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Вот текст ошибки.

```
[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ars\\python\\book\\задание.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\user\Desktop\ars\python\book]
[path: C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe]
[Finished]
```